# Proving that $\mathcal{L}(x_n+y_n) \subset {\cal L}(x_n)+{\cal L}(y_n)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be two bounded real sequences. Let: $${\cal L}(x_n) =\{ L \in [-\infty,+\infty] \mid L \text{ is the limit of some subsequence }(x_{n_k}) \},$$ and the same for ${\cal L}(y_n)$ and $\mathcal{L}(x_n+y_n)$. I want to prove that $$\mathcal{L}(x_n+y_n) \subset {\cal L}(x_n)+{\cal L}(y_n).$$

If I take $L \in \mathcal{L}(x_n+y_n)$, then I have $\lim_k (x_{n_k}+y_{n_k}) = L$ for some convenient subsequence. I wanted to write $L = \lim_k x_{n_k}+ \lim_k y_{n_k}$ to conclude that $L \in {\cal L}(x_n)+{\cal L}(y_n)$, however I do not know how to guarantee (or even if it is really true) that these last two limits do exist. Can someone give me a hand, please? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by a "limited real sequence"? Is it "bounded"? If so, then take a converging subsequence of $x_{n_k}$ (then the corresponding subsequence of the $y_{n_k}$ must be converging too).

Comment: I am sorry, I meant bounded. Forgot that the term was another in english. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), take a converging sub-sequence of $x_{n_k}$, say 
$x_{n_{k_j}}\to X$. Then it must be the case that $y_{n_{k_j}}\to L-X$.
So $L=X+(L-X)\in {\cal L}(x_n)+{\cal L}(y_n)$.

Comment: I think I figured it in my last comment in the other answer. I just wanted to look at all the details, since I'm not used to wokring with subsequences like this. Your $(x_{n_{k_j}})$ helped a lot. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

If by 'limited' you mean bounded then from your original sequence $x_n$ s.t. $x_n + y_n \rightarrow L$ you can extract a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$. take another sub-subsequence from $y_{n_k}$ and you're done. Is this what you meant?

Comment: you do not need "another sub-subsequence"

Comment: It is not clear to me how to extract such subsequence..

Comment: IvoTerek - look up Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, @user48481MirkoSwirko - right, you don't really need to do that, could argue otherwise by using the original limit, but it's still fine

Comment: Let me see. I have a subsequence $x_{n_k}+y_{n_k} \to L$. Well, $(x_{n_k})$ is a bounded sequence, so I can take $(x_{n_{k_\ell}})$ yet another convergent subsequence. Then: $$x_{n_{k_\ell}} + y_{n_{k_\ell}} \to L$$ still. From $(y_{n_{k_\ell}})$ I can extract yet another one, and then I can break the limit into two like I wanted in the original question?

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank you both!